# Adding additional field groups on a live form in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I've been stuck researching this for several days and can't seem to find the answer, or if it's even possible. I've found things that are close, but none that solutions.

I want to have a form that has a group of fields (e.g., First Name, Last Name, Email) that when filled out and submitted, stores the data in a database. I also want the ability to click a button ('+' or add new, or whatever) that would show another set of those same fields that could be filled out with different data. This would continue so that as many of these field groups as the user wanted could be added.  However, I want each group of data, as many as are submitted on the form at the same time, to be stored as separate records in the same database.

The part that I can't figure out, or know if it's possible, is the last part. The storing of the data as separate records. I can add new fields to the form, but everything that's submitted becomes part of one big record. I can't find out how to get them to be submitted simultaneously, but stored separately.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, and it's actually *somewhat* intuitive (assuming I understand your question)

For the html, you have essentially two arrays in your name fields. The number should change as you duplicate the fields. The following will produce two distinct "records", as arrays within the "person" array.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="person[1]['first']"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[1]['last']"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[1]['email']"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[2]['first']"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[2]['last']"/>
    <input type="text" name="person[2]['email']"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the PHP

```
<?
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    print_r($value);

    // $value is an individual "record." You could then insert, for example, $value['first'], $value['last'], etc. within this loop.
}

?>
```

Sample output from the above:

> Array ( [1] => Array ( ['first'] => John ['last'] => Matthews ['email'] => email1@email.com ) [2] => Array ( ['first'] => Carol ['last'] => Martinex ['email'] => email@email.com ) )

Hope this makes sense, I can try to clarify if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm going to try this out and see if it works and I'll definitely let you know if I need any further clarification. I really appreciate your help.